# Watson document conversion not working for my downloaded pdf files

Tags: ibm-watson

i tried following the steps mentioned "https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/document-conversion-nodejs" and is able to load the app which works well with sample pdf file.

But when i try using my pdf file it throws error "Missing required parameters: 
either params.file or params.document_id must be specified"
Also in the above mentioned git hub link the step 7 is not clear, it mentions run node setup.js but i am not able to find out that file.

has anybody faced this kind of issue.Kindly reply.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for pointing out the confusing step 7 in the document-conversion-nodejs repo. That's not a valid step and I've submitted a pull request to remove it.

You should be able to change the sample files with your own, if this is what you are trying to do. I would need to see some of your code to maybe figure out what is going on with it.

There is an alternative repository [watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk] that you also can use to create your NodeJS application. It also has an example (examples/document_conversion.v1.js) on how to run the service.

Besides entering your service credentials, all you need to do is place the document you want to convert in the "resources" folder and point to it in  this line:

> fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/resources/YOUR_DOCUMENT')

The [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/document-conversion/tutorial.shtml) and the [API documentation](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/document-conversion/api/v1/) could also be of help.